# Error when trying repo init on external drive on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, android-source, symlink, repo

I'm trying to init repo of Android ROM, but it returns following error on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ repo init -u git://github.com/AOSiP/platform_manifest.git -b pie
    Get git://github.com/AOSiP/platform_manifest.git
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/media/exthdd/AOSIP/.repo/repo/main.py", line 547, in <module>
        _Main(sys.argv[1:])
      File "/media/exthdd/AOSIP/.repo/repo/main.py", line 522, in _Main
        result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
      File "/media/exthdd/AOSIP/.repo/repo/main.py", line 184, in _Run
        result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
      File "/media/exthdd/AOSIP/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 426, in Execute
        self._SyncManifest(opt)
      File "/media/exthdd/AOSIP/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 188, in _SyncManifest
        m._InitGitDir(mirror_git=mirrored_manifest_git)
      File "/media/exthdd/AOSIP/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2395, in _InitGitDir
        self._UpdateHooks()
      File "/media/exthdd/AOSIP/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2416, in _UpdateHooks
        self._InitHooks()
      File "/media/exthdd/AOSIP/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2446, in _InitHooks
        os.path.relpath(stock_hook, os.path.dirname(dst)), dst)
      File "/media/exthdd/AOSIP/.repo/repo/platform_utils.py", line 195, in symlink
        return os.symlink(source, link_name)
    OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

It works when running on system drive, but I don't have enough space there.

Answer (score 1):

Drive had exFAT filesystem, error gone on ext4.